# When should sizing grip (windows Forms) be used?

Tags: winforms, sizing, grip

Should it be used for all sizable forms, or only when it is not easy to guess that a form is sizable? Is there a GUI convention to use it?

Any link to a documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Vista User Experience Guidelines:

> Resizable windows no longer must show the resize glyph in the lower-right corner, because:
>
> - All sides and edges of a window are
>   resizable, not just the lower-right
>   corner.
> - The glyph requires a status
>   bar to display, yet many resizable
>   windows don't provide status bars.
> - The resizable window borders and
>   resize pointers are more effective
>   at communicating that a window is
>   resizable than the resize glyph.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511262.aspx